# using align environment to align variables in equations

Tags: align

I am trying to create a block of equations which looks like this.

[image]

I have the align environment as follows but it is not closely mirroring the image I had attached,

```
\begin{align}
  \text{min}  & & & &\beta \nu\\     
  \text{s. t.} &            A&x         &-b\tau     &-r_{p}\nu &= 0 \\     
               -A^{T}&y     &           &+c\tau     &-r_{d}\nu &\ge 0 \\     
               b^{T}&y      -c^{T}&x    &           &-r_{g}\nu &\ge 0 \\  
               r^{T}_{p}&y  +r^{T}_d&x  &+r_{g}\tau &          &= -\beta\\\ 
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array`. I wouldn't push `\beta\nu` too far away from the “min” operator.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
  &{\min{}}       && \beta \nu\\
  &\textup{s.~t.} &&
    \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \begin{array}[t]{ *{4}{r >{{}}l<{{}}}}
                 & &       Ax &-&     b\tau &-& r_{p}\nu &= 0 \\
         -A^{T}y & &          &+&     c\tau &-& r_{d}\nu &\ge 0 \\
          b^{T}y &-&   c^{T}x & &           &-& r_{g}\nu &\ge 0 \\
      r^{T}_{p}y &+& r^{T}_dx &+& r_{g}\tau & &          &=-\beta
    \end{array}
    \\
  &  && \hphantom{-}y\in R^m, x\ge0, \tau\ge0, \nu\in R
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]